# Auth::attempt($credentials) always returns false

Tags: php, laravel

Hi there I am new to laravel and I am trying to code functionality of my login form here are the codes:

this is how I create new user (works well)

```
public function action_newuser()
{

    $email = Input::get('email');
    $password = Input::get('password');
    $new_user = Input::get('new_user', 'off');
    $first_name= Input::get('firstname');
    $last_name= Input::get('last_name');
    $username= Input::get('username');

    $user = new User();
    $user->email = $email;
    $user->password = Hash::make($password);
    $user->first_name =$first_name;
    $user->last_name= $last_name;
    $user->username= $username;
    try{

        $user->save();
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        echo "Failed to create new user!";
    }
```

This is my login function:

```
public function action_login()
{   

    $password = Input::get('password');    
    $username= Input::get('username');
    $remember= Input::get('remember', 'off');
    if($remember =='off')   $remember=FALSE;
    if($remember =='on') $remember=TRUE;
    $credentials = array(
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
            'remember' => $remember   
        );
     if( Auth::attempt($credentials)) 
        {
            return Redirect::to('dashboard/index');
        } 
        else 
        {
            #I put this line to check are the values passed from my form are correct.
            echo $password.'  ' .$username.' '. $remember;

        }


}
```

When I submit login form it always shows a blank page has values of $password, $username and $remember values. This means Auth::attempt() is not working well.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Is `$remember` really a credential?

Comment: @WaleedKhan no problem with that. Auth::attempt takes arguements as array('username', 'password', 'remember')

Comment: @HasanAyan not really, the built-in remember is the second argument of attempt(array $credentials, boolean $remember). Additional arguments in the first array are user columns you are trying to match, like in a where clause. http://laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fool me!
Although I have checked it many times, I could not see the line `'username' => 'email',`  in auth config file.

it should be `'username' => 'username',` since I am going to use username for login.

Comment: Good observation. Such errors often go unnoticed. Has happened with me plenty of times.

Answer (score 3):

Check to make sure that your database password field is 60 characters.

Comment: its allready 60 characters. I have checked password and hashed_password using Hash::check() and it returned true. No problem with that.

Answer (score 1):

**To all laravel 4 developers who are facing the Auth::attempt() login failure with valid creditials!**

Solution:

- **In app/config/app.php change type:  'cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 to 'cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 and re-hash all passwords**
- In Model add method:

  ```
   public function setPasswordAttribute($pass) {

       $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($pass);
   }
  ```
- In UserController:

  //Create User or Register

  ```
     public function postCreate() {

      $input = Input::all();
      $user = new User;
      $user->username = Input::get('username');
      $user->email = Input::get('email');
      $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));    
      $user = User::create($input);
      return Redirect::action("Frontend\HomeController@index");
  ```

  }

  //Login or Sign in

  ```
  public function postSignin() {

      $userdata = array(
          'username' => Input::get('username'),
          'password' => Input::get('password')
      );

      if (Auth::attempt($userdata, true)) {
           Session::put('username', Auth::user()->username);
           return Redirect::action("Frontend\HomeController@index");
      } else {
           return Redirect::action("Frontend\UserController@getLogin")
                  ->with('message', 'Your username/password combination was incorrect')
                  ->withInput();
  }
  ```

Hope i have helped someone out there