# Laravel Authentication not working and never return true

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I am new in Larave and I made a login form that not working, I searched a lot about this problem and I found these questions and answers that not working for me:

1. [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181546/laravel-4-authentication-not-working)
2. [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231234/authattemptcredentials-always-returns-false)
3. [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181546/laravel-4-authentication-not-working)

I read these 3 questions and again not working:

This is my **users** table:

> id  |  username  |  password  |  remember_token  |  created_at  |  updated_at
>
> 1  | e@so.com|  testpass1

This is my **User** Model:

```
    <?php
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;
    public static $auth_rules=[
        'email'=>'required|email',
        'password'=>'required|between:3,18'
    ];
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');
}
```

This is my route:

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'admin','before'=>'Auth'),function(){
    Route::resource('posts','AdminPostsController', array('except'=>array('show')));
});
```

This is Filter(**Auth**):

```
 Route::filter('Auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest('admin/login');
        }
    }
});
```

and this is **AdminAuthController** that route send data from login to **AdminAuthController@postLogin**:

```
  //This is postLogin method:
    public function postLogin(){
     //Showing username and password
      echo 'Username:'.Input::get('email').'<br/>';
     echo 'Password:'.Input::get('password').'<br />';

     //If username and password: return true
  dd(Auth::attempt(array('username'=>Input::get('email'),'password'=>Input::get('password')     )));
   }
```

This is what Laravel return in browser:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cq61.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel Auth::attempt() always false?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006597/laravel-authattempt-always-false)

Comment: @MattBurrow Yes I didn't see that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password in your table needs to be **hashed**!

You can use `Hash::make('password')` to generate a hash of the password. If you want to update your db manually in development you can use `artisan tinker` to quickly generate a hash:

```
php artisan tinker
> echo Hash::make('your-secret-password');
```

Copy the output and update the password field in your db.

**Note** the db field needs to be at least **60 characters long**

Comment: Yes exactly. The output should be something looking like this: `$2y$10$xdWRiQr6TQxj/4Ll/6iAfeTYcsVrH1MwvFpNLz3dpX/8M3t8h1W42`

Comment: Really really really thanks. I hope you the bests. I will tick the green magical button to tell Stackoverflow this is my selected answer